# Fetching events from database into FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, php, json, fullcalendar

I am trying to fetch data from a MySQL database into a calendar. (FullCalendar plugin)
I want to send the fetched data as a json feed to be displayed on the calendar.

This is my Javascript code for displaying the events:

```
events: {
        url: 'http://localhost/Hotel/event_source.php',
        error: function() {
        alert('There was an error while fetching events.');
        }
```

This is the event_source.php page where I'm fetching the data from the database:

```
<?php
     include('hoteldb.php');
     global $conn;
     if($stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT title, startDate, endDate FROM event"))
     {
       $stmt->execute();
       $stmt->bind_result($title, $startDate, $endDate);
       while ($stmt->fetch()) 
       {
            $rows[] = array('title' => $title, 'startDate' => $startDate, 'endDate' => $endDate);
       }
       $stmt->close();
       echo json_encode($rows); 
      } 
?>
```

Comment: So whats your requirement ?

Comment: The events aren't being displayed on the calendar

Answer (score 0):

The code should be modified as followed. The statement **fetch** method will return the next row and you have to catch it as follows. Also the columns are accessed as I have shown in the following code.

```
$rows=array();
while ($row=$stmt->fetch()) 
{
    $rows[] = array('title' => $row['title'], 'startDate' => $row['startDate'], 'endDate' => $row['endDate']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Below one in your while loop

'title' and 'start' must be there in event to load in calendar.

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) 
{
    $rows[] = array('title' => $title, 'start' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($startDate)),  'end' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($endDate)));
}
```